How does a pilot communicate with ATC during a hijacking?
How does a pilot communicate with ATC during a hijacking?

Such information will reduce effectiveness of communication. If it is just for curiosity, I assume old reports may help to get an idea (and details will change from time to time), there were various hidden ways -- Large terrorist organizations know the answer, but a lot of hijacking happens from desperate (or drunk) people (not all planes depart from international airports and/or western countries, not all are the big planes)

They set their transponder to 7500, which signifies a hijacking is talking place. ATC would then likely communicate with police etc.
